# (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setNotification on channel xyz.luan/audioplayers))

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, flutter-audioplayers

I am using audioplayers 0.16.1 library for my music application but I keep getting the following error while building notifications. My Error Code:

```
Exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setNotification on 
channel xyz.luan/audioplayers))
```

My setNotification method:

```
  setNotification() async {
await advancedPlayer.setNotification(
    albumTitle: "Beatifun Music",
    artist: video.snippet.channelTitle,
    duration: _duration,
    elapsedTime: _position,
    backwardSkipInterval: Duration(seconds: 10),
    forwardSkipInterval: Duration(seconds: 10),
    imageUrl: video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
    title: video.snippet.title);
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: are you using a pub package. I suggest that you verify the version of he package still uses the same functions. This happens mainly when the creator of the package switches the names of the functions

Comment: I using audioplayers package in pub.dev. them version is 0.16.1

Comment: can you specify how you initialized advancedPlayer

Comment: Future initPlay() {
    advancedPlayer = AudioPlayer(
      playerId: widget.playlist[widget.currentIndex].snippet.resourceId.videoId,
    );
    audioCache = AudioCache(
      fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer,
    );

    advancedPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
          _duration = d;
        });

    advancedPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
          _position = p;
        });
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version (3.0.1) of [AudioPlayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers), it should be solved there.